# HtmlUnit generates warning for invalid css

Tags: java, jquery, htmlunit

We are using htmlunit for our functioal test and it works very well. One of the issue I have seen is in build, it generates some warning messages:

```
ERROR [main] (StrictErrorReporter.java:80) - runtimeError: message=[An
invalid or illegal selector was specified (selector: '.page-container
.order-completed-selector[data-product-number=0022002]' error: Invalid
selectors: .page-container
.order-completed-selector[data-product-number=0022002]).]
sourceName=[http://localhost/resources/scripts/lib/jquery-1.7.2.js]
line=[5138] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
```

I am not sure what is the exact reason since it works fine at browser level and tests also pass. But it looks to me that it doesn't like attribute `[data-product-number=0022002]`. Does anybody know what can be the reason for the same?

Comment: I'm not sure about the specification, but have you tried putting the number into quotes (`[data-product-number="0022002"]`)? You might as well be interested in http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/.

Comment: Thanks... Spot on. I changed it to single quote(') and worked fine. Could I ask you to make your comment as answer for the benefit of other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the number into quotes:

```
[data-product-number='0022002']
```

(I think both, `"` and `'` should be correct by CSS specification.)